# Bootstrap navbar - drop downs not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've put together a navbar with bootstrap and I've noticed that the collapse drop down does not work.  While playing with this, I've added the example code from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and not only does the collapse dropdown not work, none of the example drop downs on this navbar work.  I've tried removing all other stylesheets to make sure there are no conflicts, but no help.  I'm using bootstrap 3.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_dropdowns.asp) you can find working examples of Bootstrap Dropdown Components. Hope it will help.

Comment: This led me to the solution.  Which was that I was not including the bootstrap.js in my scripts download.  Thanks for responding to such a lame brained problem!